# Consultar archivo xml desde sql server con OPENROWSET

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, file

estoy realizando una consulta a un archivo xml desde un store procedure y al colocar la ruta directa funciona. el problema es que la ruta quiero pasarsela por parametros y me arroja error al colocarsela como variable

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn
FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\example\mixml.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x;
```

Asi lo hice y funciona pero al aplicar el cambio de abajo y colocar la ruta en una variable @file dice sintaxis incorrecta.

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML;
DECLARE @file varchar(max);

set @file = 'C:\example\mixml.xml';

SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn
FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK @file, SINGLE_BLOB) x;
```

Alguien puede ayudarme con esto?

Answer (score 1):

Has intentado usando un query dinámico? Algo como esto,

```
    DECLARE  @XmlFile   xml;
    DECLARE  @file      varchar(max);
    DECLARE  @Query     nvarchar(max)

    SELECT  @Query          =   'SELECT @varOut = BulkColumn
                        FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK ' + @file + ', SINGLE_BLOB) x;'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query, N'@varOut xml out',@varOut=@XmlFile out

    SELECT @XmlFile
```